# Change precision of RFC parameter in OData service builder?

Tags: odata, abap, saprfc, sap-gateway

I am using SAP function `BAPI_TRADINGCONTRACT_GET_LIST` in which there is property `reqquality` whose type is `edm.decimal`, precision is 13 and scale 3. I want to edit it, but can't do it. How can I change the scale value to 2?

Or how can I edit a property of the RFC module? 
Or any other procedure to handle the properties?

Comment: Hi, try harder please. What have you tried so far? Do you have some code to show? Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether the Odata model is a custom one or if you are using an existing SAP delivered one (in the SAP namespace).

If you are using a SAP standard one, I would check if SAP has provided a Business Add In (BADI) to enhance the metadata model and associated data provider - for common Odata models SAP provides extension capabilities, here I would just add a new field and set it to the precision you require.

If the above is not available you could create a new Odata Model (using transaction SEGW) and wrap the function as per this tutorial - http://scn.sap.com/people/volker.drees/blog/2012/10/26/step-by-step-guide-to-build-an-odata-service-based-on-rfcs-part-1

Good Luck..

Comment: changing Odata model will not change RFC it calls under the hood, so it is useless